# The architecture for server part of a Client-Server app

Tags: php, android, security, architecture, client-server

I want to implement the server part of a client-server application, Some sort of interaction between Android and PHP. but I don't know if there is a structured method for implementing server part in PHP. I use files like create-user.php that get parameters from Android app and do some queries on database and this works fine!! But this does not convince me. I have seen patterns like `RestUtils::sendResponse(200, json_encode($output), 'application/json');` in StackOverflow that do the same thing that i do, but in some good looking fashion.

My questions:

1. if there are best practices please refer me to them.
2. what is the best Request method (among GET and POST) for tasks like signup?
3. how can I boost my applications security? I have a signin but this is a very common user & pass check. I this project was all on web I can use cookies to secure the app. But because of being client server I dont know how to boost security? if anyone without singing in request some of my php scripts I dont know how to prevent this.

Please Help Me with referring me to pages..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my answers:

2) Both GET and POST can be used depending on what you are doing, normally GET is used for simply getting information, like pulling a user's info, POST is normally used for sending info, basically just about anything with a form submitting data.

3) To help increase security you could just append another GET variable, then in your php the first thing you can do is see if that variable is set to the correct value. If not just kill the script. This way if someone by chance browses to 'yourdomain.com/create-user.php' it won't work, they would need to browse to 'yourdomain.com/create-user.php?appkey=189381823' or something like this.

Comment: Something like IMEI or the MAC address of the user's device that captured in the signup time. Correct?